# PowerBI API to send filter parameters and related data to existing pbix report and send it Options

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, powerbi

I have pbix already created in my workspace with a given report id.
I am creating a .net core mvc web application. From my web application i will call PowerBI API.
I will pass on the filter parameters and email id.
Based on filter parameter report should be sent to the mentioned email id by PowerBI.

which API is useful for me?

Comment: There is no API that will allow you to send report by e-mail. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I should be able to send report to emaild  from within my web application (.net core).  Email id is filled by user in web application itself.

Comment: You can't send reports by e-mail. There is no API that will allow you to export the report to a file, which you can attach to the e-mail message. You can only send links to these reports, but in this case you must make sure the user has rights to see it.